# Limit no of records fetched by a query

Tags: c#, .net, oracle9i, recordset

I have a table with 100 K records. I am writing an XML file based on this recordset. I need to write 100 records to a file at a time. So I will have 1000 separate files.

Currently to limit number of records getting written to a file, I am using the

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ROWNUM  < 100;
```

This fetches 100 records and writes them to a file. When I do this again, it will fetch the same 100 records once again. Is there some way of eliminating the records it has already written?

I thought of creating a table where I will insert the primary key of each record that has been written to a file.
So I will then do

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ROWNUM < 100 AND PRIMARYKEY NOT IN (SELECT PRIMARYKEY FROM ANOTHERTABLE);
```

I am using Oracle 9i and a console based c# app. I use ODP .NET to make the connection.

Is there any other way to do this process?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just fetch the entire 100K records and use a couple for loops?  100K isn't that many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your `select`  statement should be ordered, otherwise you aren't guaranteed to get the same 100 rows every time.

What you could do is have a dynamic query (if you don't want a stored procedure than just build the string and subsitute `:start` and `:end` with actual numeric values before executing the query) that limits `rownum`, maybe something like:

```
select *
from(
    select table.*, rownum rn
    from table
    where rownum rownum < :end
    order by ID) s
where s.rn >= :start
```

**UPDATE**

I do agree with Scott Anderson, why not just get all records at once and separate the records into groups of 100's in your front-end system?

Comment: The above query won't return any rows if :start is 2 or greater. You would need something like. select * from ( select a.*, rownum rnum from ( YOUR_QUERY_GOES_HERE -- including the order by ) a where rownum <= MAX_ROWS ) where rnum >= MIN_ROWS http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:127412348064

Comment: @RussllH: Indeed, I'd forgotten that twist. I will update. ;)

Answer (score 2):

A general solution for limiting the records fetched by Oracle has been given by Tom Kyte.

```
select * 
  from ( select a.*, rownum rnum
           from ( YOUR_QUERY_GOES_HERE -- including the order by ) a
          where rownum <= MAX_ROWS )
 where rnum >= MIN_ROWS
```

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:127412348064

I also agree with Scott Anderson that in this case just fetch all the records and use a couple loops.